# Swiping through views in Android

Tags: android, view, fragment, swipe

I have seen a lot of answered questions about this, but none about what I exactly want so here it goes (if there's an answered thread about this I'd appreciate it):

I want to create a kind of "level selection" app, where you basically have to swipe from right to left in order to be able to see the next list of levels, however I want to do it WITHOUT tabs (haven't found out how to do it yet).

Thanks.

EDIT: Solved it by simply using a ViewPager without even bothering or paying attention to the ActionBar part Android tells you to add (I just created my few fragments, my viewpager, and this last one did the rest, didn't even need to use a gesture detector for swipes as viewpager already provides this animation).

Any ViewPager Tutorial teaching you how to swipe between tabs basically has all the information I needed :) Thanks everyone!

Comment: So without a viewpager ?

Comment: Yeah, I just want the view and the "swipe action" that will go to the next view, kinda just like a game would make you select a level out of a huge list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Solved it by simply using a ViewPager without even bothering or paying attention to the ActionBar part Android tells you to add (I just created my few fragments, my viewpager, and this last one did the rest, didn't even need to use a gesture detector for swipes as viewpager already provides this animation).

Any ViewPager Tutorial teaching you how to swipe between tabs basically has all the information I needed :) Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

For doing this you shiuld use `ViewPager`
Its easy !

1. Layout ViewPager

   ```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/vpPager"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
   ```
2. Define Fragments

   public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
       // Store instance variables
       private String title;
       private int page;

   ```
   // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
   public static FirstFragment newInstance(int page, String title) {
       FirstFragment fragmentFirst = new FirstFragment();
       Bundle args = new Bundle();
       args.putInt("someInt", page);
       args.putString("someTitle", title);
       fragmentFirst.setArguments(args);
       return fragmentFirst;
   }

   // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       page = getArguments().getInt("someInt", 0);
       title = getArguments().getString("someTitle");
   }

   // Inflate the view for the fragment based on layout XML
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
       TextView tvLabel = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvLabel);
       tvLabel.setText(page + " -- " + title);
       return view;
   }
   ```

   }
3. Setup FragmentPagerAdapter

   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
       // ...

   ```
   public static class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
   private static int NUM_ITEMS = 3;

       public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
           super(fragmentManager);
       }

       // Returns total number of pages
       @Override
       public int getCount() {
           return NUM_ITEMS;
       }

       // Returns the fragment to display for that page
       @Override
       public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           switch (position) {
           case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
               return FirstFragment.newInstance(0, "Page # 1");
           case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
               return FirstFragment.newInstance(1, "Page # 2");
           case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
               return SecondFragment.newInstance(2, "Page # 3");
           default:
               return null;
           }
       }

       // Returns the page title for the top indicator
       @Override
       public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
           return "Page " + position;
       }

   }
   ```

   }
4. Apply the Adapter

   public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
       FragmentPagerAdapter adapterViewPager;

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
       ViewPager vpPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.vpPager);
       adapterViewPager = new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
       vpPager.setAdapter(adapterViewPager);
   }

   // ...
   ```

   }
5. Setup OnPageChangeListener

   // Attach the page change listener inside the activity
   vpPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

   ```
   // This method will be invoked when a new page becomes selected.
   @Override
   public void onPageSelected(int position) {
       Toast.makeText(HomeActivity.this, 
                   "Selected page position: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }

   // This method will be invoked when the current page is scrolled
   @Override
   public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
       // Code goes here
   }

   // Called when the scroll state changes: 
   // SCROLL_STATE_IDLE, SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING, SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING
   @Override
   public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
       // Code goes here
   }
   ```

   });

if you need more info see this link (it also explain how to use tabs) :

https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter

Comment: As far as I've read a ViewPager gives the effect of tabs, I just want a list of levels (example, in the first page from Level 1 to 20, in the second from 21 to 40...) but I don't want any tabs, just the view with the levels and the swipe action.

Comment: i hope this link can help you : http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging

Comment: I'll try it, although I think the ViewPager it's talking about is what I don't want, but thanks! :)

Comment: i think if you want to use fragments ViewPager is the easiest way ! but mybe you do smething with animations !

Answer (score 0):

You have to use **`HorizontalScrollView`** (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/HorizontalScrollView.html) which will manage horizontall scroll by himself. Juste place other view inside and you're good.

Comment: That's actually a really good way to solve my issue, I'd just have to not show the scrollbar itself and I'd be good. Nonetheless I kinda want the effect of ViewPager, just without the tabs it provides, as in swipe -> next page of levels, but not showing the tabs. If I cannot find a way to do this I'll definetely use the horizontal scrollbar, Thanks!